# How to access tax information for pos order lines in Odoo 12

Tags: javascript, relation, odoo-12, point-of-sale

I am using Odoo 12 point of sale and have the need to access every tax included on each pos order line and make some logic depending on the tax configuration (tax name, tax amount and some custom fields I added).

For instance:

```
var OrderlineSuper = pos_model.Orderline;
pos_model.Orderline = pos_model.Orderline.extend({
    export_as_JSON: function(){
        var data = OrderlineSuper.prototype.export_as_JSON.apply(this, arguments);
        data.test_field = this.product.display_name;

        //Here I need to browse through every tax included on pos order line (access taxes fields) and make some logic

        console.log('DATA:', data);
        return data;
    },
});
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the order line [get_taxes](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/point_of_sale/static/src/js/models.js#L1557) method.

```
this.get_taxes().forEach(function (tax) {

});
```

Comment: Dear @Kenly... you once again. Thank you very much my friend. Best regards